send telegram verification code with sms in mtproto telegram api
I'm working on a project to scrape data from my channels. When I use the auth.sendCode method, it sends the verification code to my Telegram account. I don't want to get the verification code from Telegram - I want to get it from my cell phone's SMS instead.
Is there a way to have the verification code sent via SMS instead of to my Telegram account? I've searched a lot but couldn't find a solution. If someone could help me with this, I would really appreciate it.
